# Find marginal distribution for Pareto prior

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have the following problem:

> The prior distribution for $\theta$ is distributed $\pi(\theta) = \frac{aP^a}{\theta^{a+1}}$, $\theta >P$
>
> The likelihood for X is uniformly distributed, i.e. $f(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$, $0 \leq x \leq \theta$
>
> How do I determine the marginal distribution of Y, and how do I show whether the Pareto the natural conjugate for $\theta$?

I am stuck on calculating the marginal with integral $\int_P^\infty\frac{aP^a}{\theta^{a+2}}d\theta$

Comment: You seem to be mixing $x$ and $P$ both in the prior and the likelihood.  Perhaps the prior should have $\theta \gt P$ and the likelihood should have $0 \le x \lt \theta$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_P^\infty\frac{aP^a}{\theta^{a+2}}d\theta = \left. -\frac{1}{a+1}\frac{aP^a}{\theta^{a+1}} \right|_P^\infty = \frac{a}{(a+1)P}$$

but your posterior distribution and indeed your integral should take different forms depending on whether $x \le P$ or $x \gt P$ as you know $\theta \ge x$.

*Added:*

If $x \gt P$ then $\Pr(\theta \lt x|X=x)=0$ so your integral should have $x$ as its lower limit rather than $P$, giving $$\int_{\max(x,P)}^\infty\frac{aP^a}{\theta^{a+2}}d\theta =  \frac{a P^a}{(a+1)\max\left(P^{a+1},x^{a+1}\right)}$$ and a posterior density of  $$\frac{(a+1)\max\left(P^{a+1},x^{a+1}\right)}{\theta^{a+2}}$$ when $\theta \ge \max(x,P)$.

Comment: Why does: $\frac{aP^a}{\theta^{a+1}} |_{\theta=\infty} = 0$?

Comment: Also, what do you mean the posterior will take different form based on the x>/<P - can you show some difference between the workings?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \to \infty} \frac{1}{\theta^{a+1}} =0$ for non-negative  $a$. As $\theta$ grows, $\frac{1}{\theta^{a+1}}$ gets smaller.

Comment: If $x \gt P$ then $\Pr(\theta \lt x|X=x)=0$ so your integral should have $x$ as its lower limit rather than $P$, giving $$\int_{\max(x,P)}^\infty\frac{aP^a}{\theta^{a+2}}d\theta =  \frac{a P^a}{(a+1)\max\left(P^{a+1},x^{a+1}\right)}$$ and a posterior density of  $$\frac{(a+1)\max\left(P^{a+1},x^{a+1}\right)}{\theta^{a+2}}$$ I will add this to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just confused by how you calculate the posterior, because I just usually use the formula $\frac{f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)}{f(x)}$ (which I assume since the previous part asked me to get f(x)) which gives me an answer of $\frac{(a+1)P^{a+1}}{\theta^{a+2}}$ - is it wrong if I leave the answer as this, or do I need the max() part like you have done? If I stated, x>P then Pr(θ<x|X=x)=0, would that be enough justification equate my answer to the same as yours with the max() in the numerator?

Comment: In the Pareto prior, $P$ is the minimum possible value for $\theta$; it is also the mode of the distribution.  If you observe an $X=x \gt P$ then combined with $0 \le X \le \theta$, you now know that $P$ was too low.